# Semantic commit type if only changed the error message

Tags: git, git-commit, conventional-commits

What is the best practice of semantic commit type if I just improved the output message to make it clearly?

**Example:**

Original output message is: `console.log('You are wrong')`

and I've changed into: `console.log('You are wrong because "a" is undefined.')`

---

I don't think **feat** or **fix** is proper to use, does **refactor** would be an answer?

Comment: It's a very minor change, but I think you could classify it as either a new feature or a fix.  It makes the behavior of the code better because it provides additional information when the error occurs.  Providing the reason is a new feature.  If you can reason that the code was flawed by that feature not being there in the first place, then it's a fix.  It's definitely not a refactor.  If it were me, I wouldn't try to put a label on it.  I'd just say "improved the information provided by a log message" and leave it at that.

Comment: It depends who's using it, for what. If one of your users is depending on the content of those error messages, then changing the message is potentially _breaking_ for them. Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: I've found there's plenty of places where its really really hard to find an obvious type in semantic commits for your piece of changes. Your change is one good example. And what about when you need to prepare your code for a database change? I would say "refactor" means re-organizing production code without any change in behaviour whatsoever. So that means it's definitely not a refactor, and it's not something else either of the defined types

Comment: @jonrsharpe Theoretically, any change to the source code could be a breaking change for some user. (Maybe a user relies on the number of characters mod 6 in the source code to determine if their computer should explode, i.e. `[[ $(($(cat **/*.py | wc -c) % 6)) == 0 ]] && rm -rf / --no-preserve-groot`.) But if the project does not define exact error output stability (or keyboard-based heating, or source code Russian roulette) to be a feature, then the project may claim that it's not a breaking change.

Comment: @JimAho I wonder if `misc:` (or whatever floats your boat) is a reasonable choice for such situations (which are quite common) where nothing fits. I've been defaulting to `feat:`, otherwise, since `fix` and `refactor` are definitely not correct.